# Spring MVC dynamically binding to and from a list of beans

Tags: list, binding, spring-mvc, javabeans, dynamic

I am new to spring MVC.In my application I need  to bind dynamically generated textbox contents to a list of beans dynamically.I went through the spring mvc book for binding to lists.But before binding, we must not only initialize
the collection, but populate it with objects.

In my case  I dont know the size of the list initially.

So is there any way to achive this ?

any help ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you don't know the size if your list by the time you prepare the model for your view, then something is wrong with your design.

Comment: @Oliver Not really. For example, when creating a new contact and you want to bind the telephones list to some UI components

Answer (score 0):

Use an org.springframework.util.AutoPopulatingList in your model.